# Ошибка в Android Studio при создании проекта

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю первые шаги в программировании под Android. Делал различные helloworld на Eclipse. Решил посмотреть AndroidStudio. Установил, обновил до 0.3.6, скачал модули Android SDK, создаю проект на андойд 2.3.3, без темы, ставлю создать активити без экшенбаров и меню. При создании получаю ошибки:

```
Information:Compilation completed with 57 errors and 0 warnings in 20 sec
Information:57 errors
Information:0 warnings
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Listener:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'.> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Listener:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\P0101_Listener\Listener\build\exploded-bundles\ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900.aar\res\values-v14\values.xml
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
    Error:Error:line (50)Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    Error:Error:line (135)Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
    Error:Error:line (134)Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\P0101_Listener\Listener\build\exploded-bundles\ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900.aar\res\values-v11\values.xml
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
    Error:Error:line (7)Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    Error:Error:Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Студия создает для проекта в папке build кучу всякой лабуды, в т.ч. и для поддержки holo. При создании проекта оставляйте в "comlpiled with" версию API по-умолчанию (4.х).